# GLTF model is not getting dragged together in three js

Tags: three.js

i created a bed model using blender and i imported it as a gltf model to use it in my three js code, it does get imported but when i applied the dragcontrols on it but i noticed that the default drag controls is grouping objects based on their material colors here is my code snippets :

`
const furnitureGroup = new THREE.Group();

```
    const loader = new GLTFLoader();
    const dracoLoader = new DRACOLoader();
    dracoLoader.setDecoderPath('/examples/jsm/libs/draco/');
    loader.setDRACOLoader(dracoLoader);

    loader.load(
        '/build/assets/models/bed01.gltf',
        function (gltf) {
            bed01 = gltf.scene.clone();
            furnitureGroup.add(bed01);
        }
    );

    const furnControls =new DragControls([furnitureGroup], camera, renderer.domElement);
    furnControls.addEventListener('dragstart', function (event) {
        OrbitControls.enabled = false ;
    });
    furnControls.addEventListener('dragend', function (event) {
        OrbitControls.enabled = true ;
    });
    furnControls.addEventListener('drag', function (event) {
        const averagePosition = new THREE.Vector3();
        modelGroup.children.forEach(child => {
            averagePosition.add(child.position);
        });
        averagePosition.divideScalar(modelGroup.children.length);
        modelGroup.position.copy(averagePosition);
        event.object.position.y = 0;
        OrbitControls.enabled = false;
    });
```

`

i was expecting the gltf model to move together no matter the material color and i had a problem again in the dragging the orbitcontrols are enabled yet in the dragstart i did set it to false and in the drag event listener too and the model position isnt getting set to 0